# Looking for a tabbed SSH solution for Linux(Ubuntu) combining PuTTY/KiTTY, WinSCP and VcXsrv

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

When i used [WinSSHTerminal](http://dl.winsshterm.net/WinSSHTerm-2.2.9.zip) , it a very good tool for Window machine to connect multipal server in session.

Please check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zX7Uv--2Js

Could you suggestion me same method/tool for linux server.

Your suggestion have always helpfull.